# Select GetDate() via VB.net different then Select GetDate() via SSMS

Tags: sql, vb.net, ssms, sql-server-2000

When I Use the below code:

```
Dim cmd As New OdbcCommand("SELECT GETDATE()", oConn)
retVal = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
```

The resulting output is:

```
8/1/2013 10:10:39 AM
```

When I run the exact same query directly in Management Studio I get:

```
2013-08-01 10:10:39.317
```

When I check my computer settings versus the SQL Server settings they match.

Anyone know what I need to do to ensure it matches?

Specifically I am talking about the Date format difference.

Comment: Have you checked the time zones on both the server and the client?

Comment: Is the difference you want explained the ~30 minutes between them, or the changes in formatting?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever the more I think about it, the more I believe that the half hour difference is irrelevant. After all, it should still be returning SQL Server's time in both cases. I think he just ran them half an hour apart.

Comment: My issue is with the date format, sorry.  And yes I insured that both server and machine have the same settings.

Comment: Which settings exactly?

Comment: I checked the region and language setting and insured it was set to the same small date format as the other machines.

Comment: I also checked the DSN and insured that it should use the setting from the Server not from the local machine, and I tried flipping that as well just to see.  Still no luck

Comment: Thos dates look the same to me. `.317` is just the full precision of the `DATETIME`

Comment: Dates don't have format. Format applies only when you convert them to string for display purposes. There is no difference in the actual date values, yet different programs (SSMS and your code) used different rules to display them

Answer (score 5):

If you want the date output with a specific string format, then you can use `CONVERT()` with a style number. For example:

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(20), GETDATE(), 22),
       CONVERT(CHAR(23), GETDATE(), 21);
```

Results:

```
--------------------    -----------------------
08/01/13 10:53:54 AM    2013-08-01 10:53:54.943
```

However, if you are using the date for things other than direct display, only apply that formatting when you are displaying it. For all other purposes it should remain a datetime type and should *not* be converted to a string.

As for the differences in the actual time value, it's not clear what problem you're talking about, but I suspect you simply ran these queries half an hour apart. If those were run at or around the same time, it looks like the server is half an hour fast - maybe it's in a different time zone or maybe it's just a lot of drift or someone not bothering to use a time service. Your application should never use the time / time zone of the client, especially if it's distributed - always use the time on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Dates have no format. Format comes into play only when you convert dates to a string. The forma used depends on who does the conversion: the server or the client?

Your VB.NET query returns a date from the server and converts it to a string when you write it to the console, a form or whatever. VB.NET uses your programm's CurrentCulture, whose defaults come from the current user's regional settings.

When you display data in SSMS, an ISO format is used so there is no ambiguity when you edit the data.

When you compare date and string values in a query, either explicitly by converting a date to a string or implicitly because you just typed `MyDate = '13/1/2013`, a conversion is made using the column's collation. Collations are inheritted so the column's collation is the same as the database's collation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
net time \\SERVER_NAME
```

Note: Obviously `SERVER_NAME` is the name of your SQL Server machine.

Do you see a 30 minute difference in the result of that call?

Comment: sorry, it's not about the 30 minutes, it's about the format difference, I should have been more clear

Answer (score -3):

I looked deeper into the code and found that some enterprising fellow had added code to a line of SQL later in the process which forces DMY format on that query.

so the code in the VB is returning the proper Date on the app machine.  Which means that there must be a difference between my computer and the app machine.

Another coder ran into the same issue and so there solution was to add the below code to the SQL that was pulling from the DB.

SET DATEFORMAT dmy

This forces the SQL to use DMY format... I removed this code Compiled and ran the EXE from the server machine and my issue dried up!

Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: ??? Neither of the formats mentioned in your question use DMY. So your "solution" is just to make everything DMY everywhere? Why? Will the next person who writes a query know to inject the SET DATEFORMAT command? So confused.

Comment: I'm not sure that's your problem guy. @AaronBertrand has already given you the right anwer.

Comment: I did not put that code in, another programmer did.  What I found is that there is a difference between my machine settings and the app server.  so when I run the code locally the date shows up different.  another coder had the same issue.  their solution was to force a date format on a query.  This query is what caused the error.  My solution was to remove his "Fix" I reran the app on the application server and all the dates came out correct again.

Comment: But, if I was to add code in to force unity in the dates no matter which machine I was on I would use Aaron Bertrand solution.  but for my specific problem it was bad code added by another coder which once removed fixed the problem.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand why this is a format problem. If you want a specific format in your application, then use the application to format it in a specific way. Say, using VB's `Format()` function, of all things.